# How to sort users by the most recent post?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have two models: `User`, and `Post` which has `user_id` column (foreign key), and `created_at` column.

I would like to sort users by the most recent post. For example, if:

```
user_id = 1, created 3 posts at: 17/05/2011, 19/05/2011, 21/05/2011
user_id = 2, created 1 post at: 22/05/2011
user_id = 3, created 2 posts at: 18/05/2011, 20/05/2011
```

the result should be:

```
user_id = 2
user_id = 1
user_id = 3
```

How would you achieve this in Rails 3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be something like:

```
Post.select(:user_id).group(:user_id).order("created_at DESC")
```

Comment: That's wrong. If, for example, there are 3 users, and each user has one post, `User.joins(:posts).size` will be 10, rather than 3.

Comment: That's almost correct. After I changed this to `order("max(created_at) DESC")`, as Denis suggested, looks like it does the trick. Though, I'm still not sure what kind of sort is done without the `max`...

Comment: @Misha: I'm assuming you're using MySQL underneath. In that case, order("created_at DESC") will be using the created_at field of one of the rows in the group -- in other words, you'll get a random order. (Other engines would reject the clause with an error.)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the RoR part, but you're looking into a group by statement:

```
select user_id, max(created_at) as created_at
from posts
group by user_id
order by max(created_at) desc
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort by the latest post you can rely on the fact that a row with the largest `id` is the latest:

```
Post.select(:user_id).group(:user_id).order("MAX(id) DESC")
```

This way you can use the existing primary key index on `id` column(and avoid having to add a new index on `created_at` column).